# Why can't I query directly on jsonb_array_elements?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have data stored as jsonb in a column called "data":

```
{'people': [{"name": "Bob", "Occupation": "janitor"}, {"name": "Susan", "Occupation", "CEO"}]}
```

I can query this via:

```
SELECT mydata.pk FROM mydata, jsonb_array_elements(mydata.data->'people') AS a WHERE (a->>'name') = 'bob'
```

Why can't I substitute "a" for the jsonb_array_elements(...)?:

```
SELECT mydata.pk FROM mydata WHERE (jsonb_array_elements(mydata.data->'people')->>'name') = 'bob'
```

Instead, I get the following:

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must not return a set
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the error message says, arguments to `WHERE` must not return a set. `jsonb_array_elements` returns a set and it can't be compared to a single value. In the second query you have a cross join inside the select and that converts it into a suitable result to use `WHERE` on.

You can also do it this way

```
SELECT mydata.pk FROM mydata
  WHERE 'Bob' in (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(mydata.data->'people')->>'name');
```

Here the subselect will allow you to use the `IN` operator to find the desired value since the result is no longer a set.

Another way is to query the jsonb directly

```
SELECT mydata.pk FROM mydata
  WHERE mydata.data->'people' @> '[{"name":"Bob"}]'::jsonb;
```

This way you don't need to convert the jsonb into a resultset and search within it.

Comment: When i query using 
```SELECT mydata.pk FROM mydata
  WHERE mydata.data->'people' @> '[{"name":"Bob"}]'::jsonb
```
I am getting the result which includes Susan dataset. Is there a way to only return bob details?