# Updating a jsonb array value with constraints in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table that has a `jsonb` type with an array and I'm trying to specifically hash/anonymize emails (via md5 or sha1) within that array that follow certain requirements. Using the dummy data below, I'm having a hard time trying to to target the `owners` array *specifically* for any emails **not** with a `@google.com`domain **or** `admin`.

```
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "admin"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "john@google.com"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "jason@facebook.com", "fred@facebook.com"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "zuck@facebook.com", "bill@google.com"
    ],
}
```

Ideally the end result should be

```
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "admin"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "john@google.com"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "dskfjld@hashed.com", "dshfjkdhsfjk@hashed.com"
    ],
},
{
    "blah": blah,
    "owners": [
        "hashfsdflksdjf@hashed.com", "bill@google.com"
    ],
}
```

The logic here probably is to iterate through every single `owners` array in the column, but not sure how the query would specifically look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `json_agg`:

```
select jsonb_set(t.data, '{owners}', 
   (select jsonb_agg(case when v.value::text = '"admin"' or v.value::text ~ 'google\.com"' then replace(v.value::text, '"', '') else md5(substring(v.value::text from '^"([\w\.\-]+)@'))||'@'||md5(substring(v.value::text from '@([\w\.\-]+)"$')) end) 
   from jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'owners') v)) 
from vals t
```

For the purposes of [demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49a4dd9b785b1016e7c0015433ac5309), the hash used is [`md5`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-binarystring.html).

Comment: appreciate the input! One weird thing to note is that for some emails (let's say `@example.com`), it outputs the value to `null`. `md5` works fine and it's hashing anything that's not google, but missing random other emails for whatever reason. Not fully understanding the logic here, and also for some reason, the ignored domain ends up with `["\"john@google.com\""]` and wondering if we can strip the extra `\` and `""`

Comment: @stoiven Please see my recent edit, I updated the solution to remove the double quotes (produced by the JSON to text conversion). Can you post an example of the emails that are failing to be hashed? It might have something to do with the regular expressions being used to parse out the name and domain from the email string.

Comment: Ah gotcha, just tried it out, and looks super good! Still a noobie at SQL, so forgive me with this. I recently edited the fiddle as well, and I think it's because the email has a `.`? @Ajax1234 I guess this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd931b09425ed5877d7c21614a3bbb6f)

Comment: @stoiven Thanks for the fiddle. Yes, the `.` separator was the issue. I have updated both the post and the demo fiddle link.

Comment: Ah, I think it also fails, when there is a `-` separator too. Like `["android@zynga-inc.com"]` @Ajax1234 cause I got a null reference here as well.

Also, for my further knowledge, any good recs for better practices or tips/tricks on SQL? I truly do appreciate all this help!

Comment: @stoiven Glad to help! I made the regular expression more robust now. In the context of this problem, I highly recommend the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) for JSON operations in Postgres, and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687945/why-cant-i-query-directly-on-jsonb-array-elements) Stackoverflow question, to give you a better feel for the subquerying at the heart of the answer above.

Comment: I can't thank you so much again! :) One _final_ thing. I have the base up and running and can possibly use this moving forward, but one thing I'm curious is that (I haven't tested it yet) if the same `jsonb` also has another array **in addition** to owners. Like if there was another parameter, like `"subowners": [ "john@people.com" ]` , would a `CASE` be sufficient working with this?

Comment: @stoiven Yes, it should, you just duplicate the subquery in two `jsonb_set` calls: `jsonb_set(jsonb_set(t.data, '{owners}', ....), '{subowners}', ...)`

Comment: Hey @Ajax1234, sorry to bug again, but maybe if you have some time to assist. I tried your suggestion, but am running into an issue with trying to extract a `scalar` option. This is an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=50f35eab2cf90f8184cf77d5548111bf). Also not sure how I would nest the `name` param in as well...

Answer (score 0):

(a) Your `jsonb` data sample has some error inside. For this answer, I will use instead :

```
[{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "admin"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "john@google.com"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "jason@facebook.com", "fred@facebook.com"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "zuck@facebook.com", "bill@google.com"
    ]}]
```

(b) Making multiple updates within a `jsonb` data is not easy with postgres. The following solution breaks down the jsonb data structure while tracking the path information that is then used when updating the jsonb data structure with the new email values.

(c) The solution is based on the `jsonb_set()` standard function which can apply only one update to a given jsonb data. So the first step is to create the function `jsonb_set_agg()` as an `aggregate` based on `jsonb_set` and which will be able to perform multiple updates to the same jsonb data while iterating on a set of records :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_set(x jsonb, y jsonb, p text[], z jsonb, c boolean)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS
$$ SELECT jsonb_set(COALESCE(x,y), p, z, c) ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg(x jsonb,p text[], z jsonb, c boolean)
(SFUNC = jsonb_set, STYPE = jsonb) ;
```

(d) Finally, the following query breaks down the jsonb data (`FROM` clause), filters the emails which must be updated (`WHERE` clause), and then updates the jsonb data with the new email values, according to the path based on the `ORDINALITY` information :

```
SELECT jsonb_set_agg(j.json_data, array[(b.id - 1) :: text, 'owners', (c.id - 1) :: text], to_jsonb('insert_here_the_new_value' :: text), true)
  FROM (VALUES ('[{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "admin"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "john@google.com"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "jason@facebook.com", "fred@facebook.com"
    ]},
{
    "blah": "blah",
    "owners": [
        "zuck@facebook.com", "bill@google.com"
    ]}]' :: jsonb)) AS j(json_data)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(j.json_data) WITH ORDINALITY AS b(json_data, id)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(b.json_data->'owners') WITH ORDINALITY AS c(json_data, id)
 WHERE c.json_data <> 'admin'
   AND NOT c.json_data ~ '@google.com$'
```

The result is :

```
[ {"blah": "blah", "owners": ["admin"]}
, {"blah": "blah", "owners": ["john@google.com"]}
, {"blah": "blah", "owners": ["insert_here_the_new_value","insert_here_the_new_value"]}
, {"blah": "blah", "owners": ["insert_here_the_new_value", "bill@google.com"]}
]
```

all the details in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=472d09f3c5956903bde5aa0e89a18a30).